# OptimizeExpression to C code

Tags: compile, code-generation, c-codegenerator

Is there a function which turns optimized expression to C code?

Calling

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[ Sin[x] + Cos[Sin[x]]]
```

returns

```
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{Compile`$1},
          Compile`$1 = Sin[x];
          Cos[Compile`$1] + Compile`$1]]
```

I would like to turn this to C code

```
float $1 = sin(x);
return cos($1) + $1;
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to write the conversion myself?

Comment: For the future googlers coming here, I have set up a github repo with my solution https://github.com/lecopivo/OptimizeExpressionToC

Answer (score 3):

So since I need it, I wrote the function myself. It is a little bit hackish approach, but it solves my problem. So any comment and suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
OptimizeExpressionToC[expr_] := 
  Module[ {optimizedExpr, mainExpr, n, m, defs, output},
   optimizedExpr = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[expr];
   n = Length[optimizedExpr[[1, 1]]];
   mainExpr = Flatten@{optimizedExpr[[1, 2, n + 1]]};
   m = Length[mainExpr];

   defs  = 
    Table[ "Real " <>   
            ToString@CForm@optimizedExpr[[1, 2, i, 1]]  <>  
           " = " <>
            ToString@CForm@optimizedExpr[[1, 2, i, 2]] <>
           ";",
            {i, 1, n}];

   output = 
    Table[ "out[" <>
            ToString[i - 1] <>              
           "] = " <>
            ToString@CForm@mainExpr[[i]] <>     
           ";",
           {i, 1, m}];
   Join[defs, output]
   ];
```

Test

```
OptimizeExpressionToC[{Sin[x] + Cos[Sin[x]] + x y, x y}]
```

outputs

```
{"Real Compile_$32 = Sin(x);",
 "Real Compile_$31 = x*y;", 
 "out[0] = Compile_$31 + Compile_$32 + Cos(Compile_$32);",
 "out[1] = Compile_$31;"}
```

Comment: There's the SymbolicC package.  You can construct a symbolic representation of the C code and convert it to a C code string in one go.  The advantage is that the symbolic representation is a Mathematica expression, so you can use all the standard expression manipulation techniques up to the point where you decide to convert to a string.  Will it be  easier here than your approach? I do not know.  It might be, but I'm not sure. Just wanted to let you know about this.

Comment: I strongly suspect that there is some mechanism in Mathematica that already does the conversion to symbolic C automatically.  But I don't know where it is and how to use it.  It is internal stuff.

Comment: I'm aware of `SumbolicC` package, but I could not figure out how it can help me in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but possibly a starting point.

You could try the [CCodeGenerator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/CodeGeneration.html) package along the lines of:

```
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]
out = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sin[x] + Cos[Sin[x]], 
              CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}]
```

then

```
CCodeStringGenerate[out , "test"]
```

will produce C code.

Comment: Yeah, In this example the generated C code is quite nice, but take for example a simple expression `x^3` and generate C code for it and you get something completely unreadable.

Comment: @tom Try with `out = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x x x,              CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}]`; the output looks very reasonable.

Comment: `x^3` was just a toy example. I have an expression which is long over 9000 of lines of code which I need to convert to C code. I do not have the time to change the form of this expression such that `CCodeStringGenerate` would give me easily modifiable code.